# error in using android-facebook-sdk

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am just not able to figure out the problem in my code
I want to login with FaceBook for my app
I have followed a tutorial from a youtube video.
in the code , I am able to login using facebook, but I am not able to implement the logout functionality.
i tried doing it. (the code for logging out is also there but still its not working)
the code is as follows:

after i click on login button:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.fb_button:

    try{

         //to check if already logged in.
         //my code never enters the following block.

    if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "loging out",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            fb.logout(getBaseContext());
                         // update_fb_buttonimage() is a function to change the image of button
                          //if logged in: it shows logout
                          // else it shows login.

                          //but somehow its not working
            update_fb_buttonimage();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

              //following is working fine.
              // but every time i click n the button, it enters this bolok of code.
              //which is not what i want. this is tobe executed only if user is not logged in
              //even if  user is logged in , program enters this code only.
              // instead of this th above "if" block should be executed.

    else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "logging in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        fb.authorize(LoginPage.this,new DialogListener(){

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                update_fb_buttonimage();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You can't login to the facebook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "unIdentified Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }} );
    }   }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        break;
      }
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

just replace the MainActivity.this with yours and updateButtonImage()

```
if(fb.isSessionValid())
    {
        try {
            fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
            updateButtonImage();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //button close session
    }
    else
    {
        fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener(){

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on Facebook error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values)
            {
                updateButtonImage();

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {

            }
        });
        //login in to facebook
    }
```

Comment: try to put your break outside the last bracket, maybe it is executing but no break because it logs out then right back in?????

Comment: the try on the outside is unnecesarry the one before if(fb.isSessionValid())

Comment: it just doesnt make sense because if its logging in, it should logout

Comment: ill edit my answer so you have what i use, same exact thing just switch the updatebuttonimage methods

Comment: probably negative rep score, because these login and logout features are depreciated, there is new methods and code for logging in and out, they still work because of backwards compatibility though

Comment: i think there is some problem with onComplete method 
i tried to add a toast there, i didnt show

Comment: hey , i had to add onActivityResult to make it working,
now my image over the button is getting changed, so hopefully my isSessionValid or oncomplete are working properly,
but now there is new error, when i click on logout (as the view is getting updated) the app crashes!! 
any ideas?